# How can I use query to filter a range where it should not contain any word from a different range?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, textjoin

I have a list of 7000+ keywords about HVAC repair and I've managed to isolate all the unique words used in each keyword (3000+ unique words). I will be picking out the words that we don't need (such as car ACs) and then use that list to essentially make a "banned" word list. How can I then use a query to "select A where A does not contain [banned word range]"?

I tried `=query(A:A, "select A where A does not contain B")` but I don't think that it's that easy. (B is the banned word range)

Here's my ongoing project:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G5tz4Ap6WRJT2ZXJm44vOxueIOJdO32Kcti1rkudB2I/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this:

```
=QUERY(A2:A, "where not A matches '^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, B2:B)&"$'", 0)
```

[image: 0]

---

for "true contain" use:

```
=FILTER(A2:A, NOT(REGEXMATCH(A2:A,  TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B2:C))))
```

[image: 00]

---

this is a bit longer but solves every possible fail you may encounter:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(
 IF(REGEXMATCH(IFERROR(SPLIT(A2:A, " ")), "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, B2:C)&"$")=FALSE, 
 SPLIT(A2:A, " "), "♦"))),,999^99)), "where not Col1 contains '♦'", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, will try. Column A however has multiple words to it separated by space.

Comment: It works like magic :O I can't thank you enough. The only problem that I have now is that Google sheets crashes if I feed it the 3000 kws+ in one go. I can work around that though.

Comment: @OnyxJasperSalape added one more solution